# What is the equivalent of running ansible -m setup --tree in a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I had our security group ask for all the information we gather from the hosts we manage with Ansible Tower. I want to run the setup command and put it into a file in a folder I can run ansible-cmdb against. I need to do this in a playbook because we have disabled root login on the hosts and only allow public / private key authentication of the Tower user. The private key is stored in the database so I cannot run the setup command from the cli and impersonate the Tower user.

EDIT I am adding my code so it can be tested elsewhere.

gather_facts.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Check for temporary dir make it if it does not exist
      file:
        path: /tmp/ansible
        state: directory
        mode: 0755
    - name: Gather Facts into a file
      copy:
        content: '{"ansible_facts": {{ ansible_facts | to_json }}}'
        dest: /tmp/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}
```

cmdb_gather.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch fact gather files
      fetch:
        src: /tmp/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}
        dest: /depot/out/
        flat: yes
```

CLI:

```
ansible -i devinventory -m setup --tree out/ all
```

Answer (score 1):

This would basically look like (wrote on spot not tested):

```yaml
- name: make the equivalent of "ansible somehosts -m setup --tree /some/dir"
  hosts: my_hosts

  vars:
    treebase: /path/to/tree/base

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure we have a folder for tree base
      file:
        path: "{{ treebase }}"
        state: directory
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Dump facts host by host in our treebase
      copy:
        dest: "{{ treebase }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        content: '{"ansible_facts": {{ ansible_facts | to_json }}}'
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: I had come up with something similar. I found that with the delegate stanza uyou suggested in the script it bombed complaining about /usr/bin/sudo and its ownership. I run the same to a file on the remote machine and then fetch it. However, ansible-cmdb will not parse the information out. When I added the formatting of the content you suggested above I got closer. There seems to be something fundamentally different in gathering facts from a playbook opposed to running ansible -m setup. I am still trying to get this to work.

Comment: Theres is absolutely nothing different, it is the exact same module. The only difference is the ability to use the --tree option in ansible ad-hoc command. You can turn off privilege escalation for the delegated tasks if you don't need to use it to write the result on localhost.

Comment: while they may be the same code the output is different when run from within a playbook. I ran the cli twice and two versions of the playbook two times each. Both of the cli runs output the first bit of the json as:
```{"ansible_facts": {"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": ["172.18.0.1", "10.6.6.41", "172.17.0.1"], ```
The scripts varied in what the first portion of the output looked like. Here is an example:
```{"ansible_facts": {"ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public":```
ansible-cmdb needs a certain format I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. While @Zeitounator had a correct answer I had the wrong idea. In checking the documentation for ansible-cmdb I caught that the application can use the fact cache. When I included a custom ansible.cfg in the project folder and added:

```
[defaults]
fact_caching=jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /depot/out
```

ansible-cmdb was able to parse the output correctly using:

```
ansible-cmdb -f /depot/out > ansible_hosts.html
```